# how to make custom blocks shape in blockly?

Tags: javascript, blockly, google-blockly

I'm trying to change the shapes of the blocks in blockly (https://developers.google.com/blockly/) to look more similar to scratch 3

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Scratch Blocks**
That's available on **github**
This is the link: https://github.com/LLK/scratch-blocks
And link of **wiki**: https://github.com/LLK/scratch-blocks/wiki